# beforeunload getting called on page refresh and href clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following function to detect browser close , or someone types some other website name etc,

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){
        return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
    });
```

But the above code is getting called for page refresh , href clicks , form submits etc

how can retrict not to run the above code in these scenarios, or am i missing some other method

any help or pointers to code will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

beforeunload gets called before the current page is being unloaded no matter where the next destination is - any other page, even on your own site,even a reload of the current URL.  The idea behind the function is to be able to ask the user about unsaved data in this particular web page so it's triggered when anything that might cause that data to be lost is about to happen.

According to the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), there is no standard for this method.  It was implemented by IE4 and copied by other browsers.

I don't see any way to know why the page is about to be closed.  Usually, the way this is used is that the page keeps track of some sort of changeflag and only prompts the user if they have important, unsaved data.

Here's [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the event data that comes this event.  You will have to devise some tests to see if you can reliably tell (across browsers) what is causing this to get called and avoid your prompt in some cases.

Comment: What specific scenarios to you want the prompt to run in?

Comment: i want when someone closes browser or if they type something in address bar go to someother website

Comment: I don't see any way to reliably tell why the page is being closed.  There are some hacks (you can find via Google) to try to detect window close based on mouse position or window size, but they look very browser specific.  You could monitor all clicks in your page to know when a click in your page happened right before beforeunload or even to monitor if a link was just clicked on in your page, but that's about all I can imagine here.

Comment: yeah even i looked at some samples we can go with either of the approaches, if we use window beforeunload , we have to check for all kind of hrefs, page refresh etc , otherwise we have to implment using co-ordinates as you said.